# i have an error after upgrading my flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-upgrade

```
Error: The getter 'accentColor' isn't defined for the class 'ThemeData'.
../…/src/numberpicker.dart:200
- 'ThemeData' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/theme_data.dart' ('/opt/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/theme_data.dart').
package:flutter/…/material/theme_data.dart:1
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'accentColor'.
        themeData.textTheme.headline5?.copyWith(color: themeData.accentColor);
```

How do I run past this to get my app to debug

Answer (score 0):

From the [`ThemeData` migration guide](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/theme-data-accent-properties#accentcolor), the closest replacement for this property is `Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary;`.